# ImageMagick refuses to render solid colored rectangle. Why?

Tags: imagemagick, pictures

I found this example in the [`imagemagik`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#solid) website:

```
convert -size 100x100 canvas:khaki  canvas_khaki.gif
```

which should generate a 100x100 khaki square in the given filename. I didn't manage to run this command on neither a mac box nor ubuntu box. Any ideas how to generate such a picture from the command line?

## Edit:

### Error generated on MAC

So here the case is probably simpler; I get the following error:

```
convert: UnableToOpenConfigureFile `colors.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/589
```

*however*, the files seems to be generated correctly.
The box is running OS X 10.6.8 and `imagemagick`'s version is 6.6.9-3.

### Error on Ubuntu

Here the case seems to be more problematic; the generated error is:

```
convert: unable to open image `canvas:khaki':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: missing an image filename `canvas.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2940.
```

Here I'm running ubuntu with kernel 2.6.38 and the imagemagick version is 6.6.0-4

Comment: why didn't it work? any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [this forum post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17690):

> Use xc: instead. The canvas: image format was recently added.

Comment: Solved the problem on the ubuntu box. Same error on the mac... :( We're almost there... Thnx anyway for your answer.

Comment: [It's just a warning](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9975). When `colors.xml` is not found, the internal color table is used.